# Does the average primeness of natural numbers tend to zero?

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

[This question was posted in MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3176228/does-the-average-primeness-of-natural-numbers-tends-to-zero). It got many upvotes but no answer hence posting it in MO.

---

A number is either prime or composite, hence primality is a binary concept. Instead I wanted to put a value of primality to every number using some  function $f$ such that $f(n) = 1$ iff $n$ is a prime otherwise, $0 < f(n) < 1$ and as the number divisors of $n$ increases, $f(n)$ decreases on average. Thus $f(n)$ is a measure of the degree of primeness of $n$ where 1 is a perfect prime and 0 is a hypothetical perfect composite. Hence $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{r \le N} f(r)$ can be interpreted as a the average primeness of the first $N$ integers.

After trying several definitions and [going through the ones in literature](http://conceptualmath.org/challenge/compositeness.html), I came up with:

> Define $f(n) = \dfrac{2s_n}{n-1}$ for $n \ge 2$, where $s_n$ is the
>   standard deviation of the divisors of $n$.

One reason for using standard deviation was that I was already studying the [distribution of the divisors of a number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2773289/sum-of-the-standard-deviation-of-the-divisors-of-a-number).

**Question 1:**  Does the average primeness tend to zero? i.e. does the following hold?

$$
\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N}\sum_{r = 2}^N f(r) = 0
$$

**Question 2**: Is $f(n)$ injective over composites? i.e., do there exist composites $3 < m < n$ such that $f(m) = f(n)$?

---

**My progress**

- $f(4.35\times 10^8) \approx 0.5919$ and decreasing so the limit if it exists must be between 0 and 0.5919.
- For $2 \le i \le n$, computed data shows that the minimum value of $f(i)$ occurs at the largest highly composite number $\le n$.

**Note**: Here standard deviation of $x_1, x_2, \ldots , x_n$ is defined as $\sqrt \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x-x_i)^2}{n}$. Also notice that even if we define standard deviation as $\sqrt \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x-x_i)^2}{n-1}$ our questions remain unaffected because in this case in the definition of $f$, we will be multiplying with $\sqrt 2$ instead of $2$ to normalize $f$ in the interval $(0,1)$.

Comment: From the linked question it seems that $s_n$ grows faster than $n$ so that $f(n)$ doesn't go to zero.

Comment: @lcv No $s_n$ doesn't grow faster than $n$. What are you looking at?

Comment: "...I wanted to have a continuous function...". In what topology is $f$ continuous? If you put discrete topology on natural numbers, then any function is continuous so you probably have something else in mind.

Comment: I have verified that $f$ is injective over composites less than 10,000,000.

Comment: @AknazarKazhymurat I have reworded that line. Hope it is clearer now?

Comment: @Nilos thank you, it is indeed clearer.

Comment: @MattF. Can you share your code? I would implement a similar code at my end. I have written one in Sagemath which is not very efficient for checking $f(m) = f(n)$ and has only verified till 12000 in half a day's run. Also what hardware are you using?

Comment: I'm using Mathematica on a $750 Windows machine:  f[n_] := 2 StandardDeviation[Divisors[n]] Sqrt[1 - 1/Length[Divisors[n]]]/(n - 1); uniques[k_] := (Table[f[n], {n, 2, k}] // Union // Length) + 
  PrimePi[k]; uniques[10000000]

Comment: I was mislead by the notation but in the linked answer it is estimated that the integrated version of $s_n$ goes like $n^2 (\log n)^\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is actually a (horrible) negative number. This matches @AsymptotiacK answer.

Comment: @NilotpalKantiSinha - This may be interesting for you. Have a look at [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/355981/is-there-a-connection-between-the-average-compositeness-of-a-rational-number-a). There is a definition of "compositeness" of a number. Here, the value approaches zero as numbers become more prime-like, and approaches infinity as they become more composite.

Answer (score 23):

The answer to Question 1 is "yes".
To see this, notice that $s_n$ is at most square root of the average square of divisor, i.e.
$$
s_n\leq \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{d\mid n}d^2}{\sum_{d\mid n} 1}}=\sqrt{\frac{\sigma_2(n)}{\sigma_0(n)}},
$$

where $\sigma_k(n)$ is the sum of $k$-th powers of divisors of $n$. Now,

$$
\sigma_2(n)=n^2\sigma_{-2}(n),
$$

so

$$
\sigma_2(n)<\frac{\pi^2}{6}n^2
$$

for all $n$. Therefore we have

$$
f(n)\leq \frac{2}{n-1} \sqrt{\frac{\pi^2}{6}n^2/\sigma_0(n)}\leq \frac{5.14}{\sqrt{\sigma_0(n)}}
$$

for all $n$. Now, almost all $n\leq N$ have at least $0.5\ln\ln N$ distinct prime factors. In particular, for almost all $n\leq N$ we have $\sigma_0(n)\geq 0.5\ln\ln N$. Therefore, our bound for $f(n)$ together with the trivial observation that $0\leq f(n)\leq 1$ gives

$$
\sum_{n\leq N} f(n)\leq \sum_{n\leq N, \sigma_0(n)\geq 0.5\ln\ln N} \frac{5.14}{\sqrt{\sigma_0(n)}}+\sum_{n\leq N, \sigma_0(n)<0.5\ln\ln N} 1= o(N),
$$

as needed.

Using contour integration method one can even prove something like

$$
\sum_{n\leq N} f(n)=O(N(\ln N)^{1/\sqrt{2}-1})
$$

Comment: That last expression reminds me [an XKCD alt-text:](https://xkcd.com/1047/)  "If you ever find yourself raising $\log(\text{anything})^{1/\sqrt{2}}$, set down the marker and back away from the whiteboard; something has gone horribly wrong."

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Bah, it was $\log(anything)^e$ not $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.  Log to the power of one over the sqrt of 2 is mundane; log of something to the power e is a sign of insanity.

Comment: @Yakk Yeah, but Randall also says that taking $\pi$-th root of anything is insane. However, the paper "Mean values of multiplicative functions" by Montgomery and Vaughan, Theorem 5, contains $(\log x)^{1/\pi-1}$ and is totally fine! (P.S. Is inequality $n_p<p^{\frac{1}{4\sqrt{e}}+o(1)}$ ok?..)

Comment: @AsymptotiacK: Thanks for the good answer to Question 1. I think that in general if  $f(n)$ is any function who value decreases from 1 to zero as its defined measure of primness decreases then the mean value of $f$ must tend to zero because as we go higher up the number line, for any $k \ge 2$, the probability of of finding numbers with $\le k$ factors should decrease