# Is the ratio of a number to the variance of its divisors injective?

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

The variance $v_n$ of a natural number $n$ is defined as the variance of its divisors. There are distinct integer whose variances are equal e,g. $v_{691} = v_{817}$. However I observed that for $n \le 10^8$ the ratio $n/v_n$ is different for each $n$.

> **Unique variance conjecture**: The ratio of a number to the variance of its divisors is injective.

**Question**: Is there any explanation why this should be true?

Note: This question was [posted in MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3310738/unique-variance-conjecture-the-ratio-of-a-number-to-the-variance-of-its-divisor) a week ago but did not get an answer

Related questions: 
[Does the average primeness of natural numbers tend to zero?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327472/does-the-average-primeness-of-natural-numbers-tend-to-zero).